# JS function returning false variable that should be true

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm having an issue with the state of a returned variable. I have the function "altFormValidate". Essentially the issue is that when I call it, if the honeypot count is 0, the validation runs fine, and the "validationResult" variable returns true, but if the honeypot count is more than 0, the "validationResult" variable still returns false, even after executing code that should make it true.

```
function altFormValidate(intendedFormID){ //Validate honeypot traps
    var validationResult = false;
    }

    var honeyPotFields = ["Fname", "EmailAddress", "Lname", "Telephone", "Address1", "Address2", "Surname", "Title"];
    var honeyPotCount = 0;
    honeyPotFields.forEach(function(entry) { //Check page for honeypots filled out
        if($('#' + entry).length >= 1){
            var honeyPotVal = $('#' + entry).val();
            if (honeyPotVal !== ""){
                honeyPotCount = honeyPotCount + 1; //Count successful honeypot traps
            }
        }
    });
    if (!honeyPotCount > 0) //Check honeypot count
    {
        $('#' + intendedFormID).attr("action", formAction); //Append SF action to form
        validationResult = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        if (honeyPotCount == 1){ //If one honeypot filled in
            //SUSPECT - implement further checks
                $.colorbox({ //init popup with confirmation input: "#machine-check"
                href: "/inc/form-confirmation.html",
                transition: "elastic",
                speed: 350,
                opacity: 0.65,
                className: "seg-window",
                onComplete: function() {
                    jQuery('#colorbox').find('a.btn-close, a.close, a.cancel').unbind('click.closeColorbox').bind('click.closeColorbox', function(e) {
                        jQuery.colorbox.close();
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
                    jQuery('#machine-check').bind('change', function(e) {
                            jQuery.colorbox.close();
                            e.preventDefault();
                            validationResult = true; //This code doesn't seem to change the variable "validationResult" when I call the entire function altFormValidate but I know that changing "machine-check" does change the variable. 
                        });
                    }
             });
        }
        else if (honeyPotCount == 2){ //If two honeypots filled in
            //PRIME SUSPECT - init Captcha/Akismet etc
            alert("Robot Alert!");
            validationResult = false;
        }

    } return validationResult;
}
```

and I call above function like so, on submit of the form:

```
   var req = true; 
   if(req){ //If required fields are filled in
                var extraValidation = altFormValidate('WebToLeadForm', 'webToLeadPost');

                 if (extraValidation == true){
                    alert("form sent");
                    //document.WebToLeadForm.submit();
                    return true;
                }
            }
```

So my question is why does extraValidation() return true if no honeypots are found, but false if one is found but the relevant code is then executed to make it true? I am thinking the issue is where I return the validationResult variable.

Comment: Asynchronicity is the problem. The `change` handler for `#machine-check` will fire long after `altFormValidate` has returned.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense! so how can I make this function work synchronously, in that the change handler would fire only after the altForm validate function?

Comment: You can't turn an asynchronous operation into a synchronous one, you should do the reverse. Prevent the actual form submission always, give `altFormValidate` a callback it should call when it knows the final value, and AJAX-ically submit the form values inside that callback. Look into how asynchronous workflow works in general.

Comment: Brilliant and descriptive, thanks @DCoder

Answer (score 3):

I didn't test it, but I guess that

```
if (!honeyPotCount > 0)
```

is not the same as

```
if (!(honeyPotCount > 0))
```

Comment: It is *far* less readable, but it yields the same result for non-negative numbers.

Comment: I don't understand what the relevance is here?

Answer (score 2):

`if (!honeyPotCount > 0)` does not do what you think it does. It does the opposite.

If `honeyPotCount` is `0` it will return `true`, otherwise it will return `false`.

Logical-not `!` has a higher [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than greater than `>`. So here's what actually happens in your if statement:

- It takes `honeyPotCount` and coerces it to a Boolean value and then returns it's inverse.

  - `!0` returns `true`
  - `!-1`, `!1`, `!2`, etc return `false`.
- That Boolean value is then [corersed to a number](http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2010/10/javascript-coercion-demystified.html) so it can be compared to `0`.

  - So, if `honeyPostCount === 0`, `!honeyPotCount === true`, `true == 1` and `1 > 0 === true`.
  - But, if `honeyPostCount === 1`, `!honeyPotCount === false`, `false == 0` and `0 > 0 === false`.

You could fix it by adding parentheses to override the precedence `if (!(honeyPotCount > 0))` meaning "if honeyPotCount is not greater than 0".
*But* it would be more readable to remove the negation from the logic and change it to `if (honeyPotCount < 1)`, meaning "if honeyPotCount is less than 1". **Even better**, you never decrement `honeyPotCount`, so you could also make it even simpler and clearer by changing it to `if (honeyPotCount === 0)`.